# About the trace class operators and their motivation

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory

What is the motivation for trace class operators? Can any body suggest the most general and standard reference that includes Schatten p class operators as well. 
I have following references

> 1. Operator theory by Conway
> 2. Operator theory in function spaces by Kehe Zhu

Can anybody suggest even better?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I took the liberty of correcting a couple of typos and adding the reference-request tag.

Comment: Generalizing Schatten classes one step further, we get noncommutative $L^p$ spaces: so maybe you could find some motivation in the survey by Pisier & Xu, in the Handbook II (p. 1459 et seq.): [click here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=sl3qiUdrXU8C&pg=PA1515&lpg=PA1515&dq=pisier+xu+noncommutative+lp+spaces+handbook&source=bl&ots=z7fDwIkomQ&sig=VJpP1nODGdZOtatlE4_OIQMpVwM&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=5-ugUsOYK8_ukQea-4GwDQ&ved=0CFMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=pisier%20xu%20noncommutative%20lp%20spaces%20handbook&f=false).

Answer (score 6):

Compact operators have a countable set of singular values $\lambda_j$ with the only possible accumulation point being zero, so to say $c_0$-sequences. If the eigenvalues are an $\ell^p$-sequence, the operator is in the Schatten $p$-class. So Schatten $p$-class operators are a noncommutative analogue of $\ell^p$ spaces. This carries over to duals, etc, making Schatten $2-$class a Hilbert space. Be careful, the analogue of $\ell^\infty$ is not compact in this setting but should be $B(H)$, the set eigenvalues may not be countable anymore, but still the spectrum is a bounded set (spectral radius $\leq$ the norm).

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you should have written "singular values" instead of "eigenvalues" in your second sentence.

Comment: No problem, Marc. By the way, I was referring to the second sentence, the one concerning $\ell_p$-norms.

Answer (score 4):

The justification for studying these operators is displayed in their name---they are the infinite dimensional operators for which a trace can be defined.  In functional
analysis, they are important since they have a natural Banach space structure for which they are the predual of the space of bounded linear operators.  Comprehensive monographs on them have been penned by Pietsch, Retherford, Simon and König.

Answer (score 0):

As a further reference you can also consult the locally convex analysis monograph of Jarchow. A very comprehensive book, I like it a lot: it has some sections on $p$-summable operators also beyond the Hilbert space case. There a lot of new phenomena appear. So this might be interesting for you to put things into a slightly bigger context.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at Barry Simon's book "[Trace Ideals and Their Applications](https://books.google.ca/books?id=-1snx2pn59cC)", especially for applications in mathematical physics.

Answer (score 0):

- MR0582655 Pietsch, Albrecht *Operator ideals*. Translated from German by the author. North-Holland Mathematical Library, 20. North-Holland Publishing Co., Amsterdam-New York, 1980. 451 pp. ([MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0582655))